# How can i make sure the css is added to my theme , it is not working

Tags: magento2, layout, css, design

I have css file design/theme/web/style.css but it is not working or maybe the thing i am adding is not responding . i have tried my own css in header of the theme it is working there but i know it is not a recommended way . how can i make my css run . 
setup:upgrade , static-content:deploy , cache:flush everything is done . but still not working .

Comment: How did you added your css to your theme and what is the exact location?

Comment: app/design/frontend/Alothemes/digitalworld1/web/css , i am using a theme i am just adding my own lines of css in this file and it is not working .

Comment: How did you call it in your theme?

Comment: I dont know the css was already in the theme , i am just trying to add my own lines in this css .

Comment: Does this css is calling in your theme or not? If not then you need to call it in your layout file.

Comment: sir look at my question please :) i have already asked how can i make sure the css is loaded or not .

Comment: Check it by view source of your page and find the style.css is loading or not?

Comment: no it is not loading i have checked it in inspect .

Comment: ok then call it from layout.

Comment: i have checked it in layout default_head_blocks.xml.
<css src="css/styles.css" />

Comment: Is it added or not?

Comment: no
i have checked it in layout default_head_blocks.xml. <css src="css/styles.css" />

Comment: but your file name is style.css so you need to add it.

Comment: no name is styles.css name is correct .

Comment: Well, correct me if i'm wrong, you have placed ypur css file in 'design/theme/web/style.css' and in layout your file path is css/styles.css ? You should have css directory in web folder.

Answer (score 0):

if custom styling is not working there could be several reason, i.e file name, in which folder file has been placed, file permission is it included in Mgento_Theme/web/css or vendor/theme/web/css.

As per question make sure your file should be less file not css file and path you add in your default_head_blocks.xml should be css ( not less ) :

i.e if i want to add mycustom.css file in theme then how it should be :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <css src="css/mycustom.css" />
</head>
```

And file path should be and name should be **mycustom.less**:

`vendor/themename/web/css/mycustom.less`

After making changes running following commands :

in Linx :

> magento-root$ rm -rf pub/static/frontend var/view-processed
>
> magento-root$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> magento-root$ php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> magento-root$ chown -R www-data:www-data ./*

in windows ( delete folders pub/static/frontend var/view-processed )

> magento-root$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> magento-root$ php bin/magento cache:flush

Hope this will help and will work for you.